# macros are not recognised in dbt

Tags: python, etl, dbt

```
{{ 
    config (
        pre_hook = before_begin("{{audit_tbl_insert(1,'stg_news_sentiment_analysis_incr') }}"),
        post_hook = after_commit("{{audit_tbl_update(1,'stg_news_sentiment_analysis_incr','dbt_development','news_sentiment_analysis') }}")
        )
}}

select rd.news_id ,rd.title, rd.description, ns.sentiment from live_crawler_output_rss.rss_data rd 
left join 
live_crawler_output_rss.news_sentiment ns 
on rd.news_id = ns.data_id limit 10000;
```

This is my model in DBT which is configured with pre and post hooks which referance a macro to insert and update the audit table.

my macro

```
{ % macro audit_tbl_insert (model_id_no, model_name_txt) % }

{% set run_id_value = var('run_id') %}

insert into {{audit_schema_name}}.{{audit_table_name}} (run_id, model_id, model_name, status, start_time, last_updated_at)
values 
({{run_id_value}}::bigint,{{model_id_no}}::bigint,{{model_name_txt}},'STARTED',current_timestamp,current_timestamp)

{% endmacro %}
```

this is the first time i'm using this macro and I see the following error.

```
Compilation Error in model stg_news_sentiment_analysis_incr 
(models/staging/stg_news_sentiment_analysis_incr.sql)
'audit_tbl_insert' is undefined in macro run_hooks (macros/materializations/hooks.sql) 
called by macro materialization_table_default (macros/materializations/models/table/table.sql) called by model stg_news_sentiment_analysis_incr 
(models/staging/stg_news_sentiment_analysis_incr.sql). 
This can happen when calling a macro that does not exist. 
Check for typos and/or install package dependencies with "dbt deps".
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your macro's definition has too much whitespace in the braces that define the jinja block:

```sql
{ % macro audit_tbl_insert (model_id_no, model_name_txt) % }
```

Needs to be

```sql
{% macro audit_tbl_insert (model_id_no, model_name_txt) %}
```

And then this should work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Reading the error, it seems that your macro is being invoked; perhaps the problem is *not* that it isn't being recognised. Note that `stg_news_sentiment_analysis_incr` is mentioned in the error log, and this appears in your first snippet as a hard-coded input to the macro executed by the book. Therefore the error appears to be occurring *after* we're already inside the macro.

So what's causing the error? On the first line it says:

> Compilation Error in model stg_news_sentiment_analysis_incr

Reading your code, I don't think that you *wanted* to compile the model. You seem to me to be trying to insert this string into an audit table. But you have written

```
pre_hook = before_begin("{{audit_tbl_insert(1,'stg_news_sentiment_analysis_incr') }}")
```

When the hooks compile, the following will be invoked:

```
{{ audit_tbl_insert(1,'stg_news_sentiment_analysis_incr') }}
```

And *there's* your problem (if I understand your objective): `'stg_news_sentiment_analysis_incr'` will be passed into the macro and interpreted as the name of a model, not as a string. [See the docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/jinja-macros#macros) - one of the examples shows a field name being passed in and *used* as a field name using this syntax.

In your macro, you write:

```
({{run_id_value}}::bigint,{{model_id_no}}::bigint,{{model_name_txt}},'STARTED',current_timestamp,current_timestamp)
```

... and it is here that the error is generated. Judging by the error text, it tries to compile the model, which calls a macro called `materialization_table_default`, which calls `run_hooks`, which tries to reference something called  `corpository_audit_tbl_insert`, which doesn't exist (at least, not at compilation time).

Comment: Paddy Alton, the model name is passed as an argument to macro. ```stg_news_sentiment_analysis_incr``` is passed to the macro is also the name of the model. The issue is because of the extra spaces in jinja block as mentioned by @tconbeer. This issue is solved.

But as you mentioned, ```stg_news_sentiment_analysis_incr``` is used to refer a column name in the log table. How to use this argument as a string value?

Comment: I imagine you would just wrap it in quotation marks `'{{model_name_txt}}'` - Jinja ultimately just has to compile to valid SQL, it doesn't really 'know' what type of 'thing' each argument is. I had thought DBT was trying to resolve the model because it wasn't going to compile to valid SQL. So what is `corpository_audit_tbl_insert` then? The macro that wasn't recognised was named `audit_tbl_insert`, so didn't appear to be the same thing.